# Javascript: Convert textarea into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, end-of-line

How would you go about breaking up a textarea value into an array, based on the end of line separation? Use of jQuery is cool by me...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This should work (tested in Firefox and Google Chrome):

```
var arrayOfLines = $('#textAreaID').val().split('\n');
```

Comment: It should be `$('#textArea').val().split('\n')`, the jQuery object doesn't have a `value` property.

Comment: @CMS - or even $('#textArea')[0].value.split('\n') :)

Comment: @CMS: Oops. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 22):

Cross-platform way:

```
var area = document.getElementById("area");             
var lines = area.value.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n").split("\n");
```

Answer (score 13):

```
var stringArray = document.getElementById('textarea').value.split('\n');
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the "cross-platform way" answer best (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32240738/34806) as I've grappled with input from a Mac in the past.  Nevertheless I think *most* of the existing answers could benefit from an additional step.

Specifically, what if some lines are empty?  The following will filter out such lines so that we wind up with a "compact" array rather than a "sparse" one (or at least, rather than one with elements containing no values)

```
var area = document.getElementById("area");             
var lines = area.value.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n").split("\n").filter(line => line);
```

Comment: To clarify, is this using the fact that an empty string is false-y in JavaScript?

Comment: @IMP1 Precisely

Answer (score 0):

You could try this function :

```
function textToArray(){
  var someArray = [];    
  var nameList = $("#txtArea").val();

  $.each(nameList.split(/\n/), function (i, name) {     

      // empty string check
      if(name != ""){

          someArray.push(name);

      }        
});
```

taken from : [CONVERT TEXTAREA CONTENT TO AN ARRAY USING JQUERY](http://yassershaikh.com/convert-textarea-content-to-an-array-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

This method worked well:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("textAreaId");
var arrayFromTextArea = textArea.value.split(String.fromCharCode(10));
```