# jquery remove textarea duplicate line

Tags: jquery, textarea

i has a problem with textarea find duplicate.

```
<textarea name="listnumber" >
12345678
12345674
12345678
12345672
12345678
</textarea>
```

and i auto remove duplicate when change using jquery.
result will be like this

```
<textarea name="listnumber" >
12345678
12345674
12345672
</textarea>
```

Question : how to remove duplicated entries in the text area. as expected result shown above

**EDIT**

i got an textarea with name="listnumber"

My Source Code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea#listnumber").bind('input propertychange keyup cut paste',function(){
        text = $("textarea#listnumber").val()
        lines = $.unique(text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/))
        count = lines.length
        $('input#totalnumber').val(count)
    });
});
-->
</script>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li><label>List Of Number</label><textarea name="listnumber" id="listnumber" ></textarea></li>
        <li><label>Total Number</label><input type="text" name="totalnumber" readonly="readonly" /></li>
    </ul>
    <a onclick="submit();" href="#" >Send List</a>
</form>
```

and i want jquery to remove the duplicate inside the textarea with using $('textarea').change(function(){}
but i dont know how to do this.
any one please help.

Comment: Nope. Didn't follow the question.

Comment: What's your question? And what's your code?

Comment: removed php tag as there is no php to be seen!

Comment: Typos on jQuery function : don't forget semi-colons.

Comment: Thanks piddl0r for remove the tag, because it is PHP project, so i put php tag, and asprin and Quasdunk sorry for my bad english and source code are now added. thanks Bigood for remind =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be helpful to you : http://jsfiddle.net/Milian/Y3WLk/

```
$("#anchor").click(function(){
    var arr = $("#txtArea").val().split("\n");

    var arrDistinct = new Array();
     $(arr).each(function(index, item) {
         if ($.inArray(item, arrDistinct) == -1)
                    arrDistinct.push(item);
     });
    alert(arrDistinct);

});
```

Comment: Hi Milian, now it got right result, but how do i replace to the textarea with the right result with newline not ','? because your link http://jsfiddle.net/Milian/Y3WLk/ not complete.

Comment: (http://jsfiddle.net/Y3WLk/5/) result correct now, but how to replace this to textarea with newline not comma?

Comment: Thansk , =D last question so how do i add filter? like remove empty line, symbol line and number less than 10 digit?

Comment: you can use regular expression for filter cases

Comment: u mean before arrDistinct.push(item);?

Comment: you can use it anywhere, before or after distinct array.

Comment: Ok,Thanks @Milian for the help. =D

Answer (score 3):

Try splitting your textarea-text into an array:
[Javascript: Convert textarea into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299604/javascript-convert-textarea-into-an-array)

And then find duplicates
[Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

Btw: time used to do this research: under a minute (incl. writing this post).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i has search it , i just dont know how to combine it to my code, because i'm still new to advance jquery.