# Extract var value in ajax call response data

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

When I execute this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});

$.getJSON(
    'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('testpage.com') + '&callback=?',
    function(data) {
        var thecontents = data.contents;
        var required = $('.testClass', thecontents).html(); 
        $("#opResult").val(required);
    }
)
```

I get the content of `.testClass` which among other things, contains:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://targetdomian.net/listener.php',
    data: 'q=1373&i='+i+'',
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#DataSecss").html(msg);
    }
});
```

Is there anyway to access `data:`'s value?

Comment: keep in mind that I do output `var required` to `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to extract the variable/value was to find/select and copy it, I tried different approach and it was to convert the whole textarea lines into array using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32240738/2213330)